# How to use python and beautifulsoup to divide one data intoto several data within one tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to use python and beautfulsoup to divided one data to several data within one tag, and year 14 to year 2014, thanks a lot !

HTML:

```
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr id="tr0" class="tableHdrB1" align="center">
      <td align="centre">C Aug-14 - 15000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Code:

```
import urllib2 
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup

contenturl = "HTML:"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'id': 'tbody'})

rows = table.findAll("tr")
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.find_all('td')
    data = [t.strip()
            for tag in cols
            for t in tag.find_all(text=True)
            if t.strip()]
    if len(data) == 1:
        print ';'.join(data)
```

Output from above code

```
C Aug-14 - 15000 ;
```

Expected output:

```
 C ; Aug ; 2014 ;15000 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your getting the data . just use split to break it and now join

```
data=["C Aug-14 - 15000"]
alldata=[]
for i in data:
    ROIdata=i.replace('-',' ')
    alldata.append(';'.join(ROIdata.split()))
```

Comment: and if it want to show more data, is that i need to add data[1], data[2] like ROIdata=';'.join(ROIdata.split()), data[1], data[2]

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the issue of turning 14 to 2014, you can either add the '20' to the front (although that would only work on millennium years) or, you can use the datetime module and strptime function that comes with the python standard library.

to borrow the python doc example:

```
from datetime import datetime 
dt = datetime.strptime("06", %y)
```

then:

```
print dt.year 
2006
```

if you're looking to read up on it, here it is! :
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime